# How to fix golang nested templates with two sets of data

Tags: templates, go, nested

I want to get two data structs into a golang nested template, I've created a struct like this for 'url' and for 'user' data like so,

```
type url struct {
    id    string
    Userid    string
    Long_url  string
    Short_url string
}
type user struct {
    Email        string
    First_name   string
    Last_name    string
    Password     []byte
}
```

I want to get the two sets of data into a nested golang template. The user data is just one set of data and the url struct will have many rows of data.

My idea is that I would create another struct like so,

```
   type Data struct {
        UU []url
        User []user
    }
```

and then do the following,

```
  bb := []url{urls}
  tu := []user{u}
  data := &Data{bb, tu}
 tp.ExecuteTemplate(w, "form", data)
```

the output of the url data is like this,

```
[{2 123 https://confluence.expedia.biz/display/INFRAENG/Graphite+Infrastructure short2} {1 123 https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/13 short}]
```

the error I get is as follows:

```
error:  "cannot use urls (type []url) as type url in array or slice literal"
```

I'm really not sure how to progress, can you help?

Comment: `urls` already seems to be what you want it to be, so you do not need this `urls := []url{urls}` step.

Comment: Can you show us the template? Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: The template is a simple {{range .}} {{.}} {{end}} however the app doesent start due to error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

https://goplay.space/#og-isDSo2oW

Always create a test case on playground to test your problem and to share with others. Hope this helps.

```
type Data struct {
    url  // embedded
    User []user
}
```